# MouseEvent of images

Tags: apache-flex, image, mouseevent, flash-builder4.5

I dynamically create images in a loop (flash builder 4.5) and when I set mouse click event, I'm using this:

```
image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void{fromThumbnail(e,i)});
```

to pass `i`. However, when I click on any image, the function thumbnail prints the last `i`.

Is there solution for this problem?

Comment: Where is i defined?  What value are you expecting it to reference?  Can you show your full loop?  If i is an instance variable, then 'fromThumbnail(e,i); will always pass the current value of the instance variable; with no consideration for what the value was when you added the event listener to the image.  If you need a reference to the image, you can use e.target in your handler function.

Comment: I'll post it as a formal answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'i' is an instance variable, then `fromThumbnail(e,i);` will always pass the current value of the instance variable; with no consideration for what the value was when you added the event listener to the image.

If you're trying to reference the image that you added the listener on, then you could use `e.target` in your handler function.